# How can I make Meteor subscriptions dynamic?

Tags: dynamic, meteor, subscription

I am looking to make my meteor subscriptions dynamic/reactive. Right now, I have a page that subscribes to a collection of templates based on a template ID that is assed to it:

Meteor.subscribe('templates', templateId)

On the same page, I have a dropdown list of template names and ID's:

```
    <p><label>Select Template</label></p>
    <select id="templateSelect" name="templateSelect">
        <option disabled selected> Select Template </option>
        {{#each orderTemplates}}
            <option value="{{this._id}}">{{this.templateName}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
```

I want the subscription variable `templateId` to be equal to the option value of the template that I select. Anyone have any ideas? I'm really not sure where to begin with this one...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a global or a template-level subscription? I.e. should the subscription to stop once you navigate to a new route/template?

Comment: hi - i want it to be a template level subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a template subscription, you should follow this strategy:

1. Create a reactive variable scoped to your template.
2. Update (1) in your event handler.
3. Use a [template subscription](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) combined with a [template autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) - this will ensure you have only one outstanding subscription and will automatically clean up the subscriptions when the template is destroyed.

```js
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'change #templateSelect': function (event, template) {
    // extract the value/id from the selected option
    var value = $(event.target).val();

    // update the templateId - whis will cause the autorun to execute again
    template.templateId.set(value);
  }
});


Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;

  // store the currently selected template id as a reactive variable
  var templateId = new ReactiveVar;

  // this will rerun whenever templateId changes
  this.autorun(function() {
    // Subscribe for the current templateId (only if one is selected). Note this
    // will automatically clean up any previously subscribed data and it will
    // also stop all subscriptions when this template is destroyed.
    if (templateId.get())
      self.subscribe('orderTemplateShow', templateId.get());
  });
});
```

Recommended reading:

1. [Scoped Reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity)
2. [Template Subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/)
3. [Changing Templates and Subscriptions with Select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637353/changing-templates-and-subscriptions-with-select-dropdown)

Comment: You're a true lifesaver!!

Answer (score 2):

To get the *id* of the selected option use a jQuery selector to select by id then select `.val()` of that menu:

```
var templateId = $('select[id="templateSelect"]').val();
Meteor.subscribe('templates', templateId);
```

Comment: gotcha, i didn't realize I could use the subscription method in a template helper file..

Comment: I'd recommend putting it in your template event handler rather than a helper in this case since you are reacting to a menu selection.