# Clear old Meteor subscription data

Tags: javascript, meteor, subscription

I have a Meteor template that uses a dynamic subscription:

```
    var templateId = event.target.value;
    Meteor.subscribe('orderTemplateShow', templateId)
```

`templateId` changes depending on the select value I choose:

```
    <p><label>Select Template</label></p>
    <select id="templateSelect" name="templateSelect">
        <option disabled selected> Select Template </option>
        {{#each orderTemplates}}
            <option value="{{this._id}}">{{this.templateName}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
```

Once I select a template, the template's information renders on a table that I have on the template.

My table:

```
 <table id="templateItems" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Member Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each templateItems}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{productCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{brand}}</td>
                    <td>{{description}}</td>
                    <td>${{memPrice}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="qty" value ="{{quantity}}"></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary removeCartItem">Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

However, when I click on a new template, data from the old template still appears on the table, in addition to data from the new template that I select. Therefore, is there a way for me to dynamically remove data from an old subscription?

Thanks!

Comment: You need an autorun and a template subscription. See my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195460/how-can-i-make-meteor-subscriptions-dynamic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subscribe to the publication, keep a subscription handle. Then when you want to cancel that subscription, invoke `.stop()` to cancel it.

```
var subHandle = Meteor.subscribe('orderTemplateShow', templateId);
...
subHandle.stop()
```

Comment: Floyd, this works great. However, I want the subscription to stop starting with the second dropdown selection and for every selection after that.  Otherwise, the subscription will stop every time I select a new template. I'll figure out something. Thank you!!

Comment: have a look at the template events http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html#template_destroyed